# what is the equivalent of tail -f in windows powershell?

Tags: linux, powershell, logging, tail

I want to get the continuous streaming of a Log file as we get using

> tail -f command in Linux

In windows how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Get-Content -Path "file" -Wait
```

Comment: with this command, it is waiting but not appending the rest of the lines

Comment: it is appending, trust me

Comment: no it is not appending..just waiting

Comment: well, if you look at the linked answer it says exactly the same, so i don't know what you are talking about

Comment: This is a proper way to do it in PowerShell.

Comment: Yeah it is working but taking too long to append lines to console, i am trying for continuous streaming of log file @sodawillow

Comment: Get-Content $fpath -tail 10